# use scrapy for instagram user login

Tags: python, scrapy

use scrapy for logging in instagram. 
i use FormRequest to post username and password. and enable `COOKIES_ENABLED = True`

my scrapy code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
class InsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'InsVideo'
    allowed_domains = ['instagram.com']

    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
    url_login = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'

    def start_requests(self):
        return [Request(self.url_login, callback=self.login)] 
    def login(self, response):
        login_post = {'username': 'username',
                      'password': 'password'}
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,  
                                          formdata=login_post,
                                          # callback=self.start_requests,
                                          dont_filter=True
                                          )]
```

i run `scrapy crawl InsVideo`, and return error message:

```
2017-03-18 12:15:49 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-03-18 12:15:49 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-03-18 12:15:49 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-03-18 12:15:52 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Received cookies from: <200 https://www.instagram.com/robots.txt>
Set-Cookie: mid=WMy0dwALAAGACJPXOYvoxHfHO00m; expires=Fri, 13-Mar-2037 04:15:51 GMT; Max-Age=630720000; Path=/

Set-Cookie: csrftoken=5JrsDnF569QLnmIzg4h0VOBRJ8gHQZZi; expires=Sat, 17-Mar-2018 04:15:51 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure

2017-03-18 12:15:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.instagram.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-03-18 12:15:52 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Sending cookies to: <GET https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/>
Cookie: mid=WMy0dwALAAGACJPXOYvoxHfHO00m; csrftoken=5JrsDnF569QLnmIzg4h0VOBRJ8gHQZZi

2017-03-18 12:15:52 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Received cookies from: <405 https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/>
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=5JrsDnF569QLnmIzg4h0VOBRJ8gHQZZi; expires=Sat, 17-Mar-2018 04:15:52 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure

2017-03-18 12:15:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (405) <GET https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/> (referer: None)
2017-03-18 12:15:52 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <405 https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-03-18 12:15:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

i dont know whats wrong with the code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your url_login is wrong, it should be https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/.

Anyway, the Istagram login page generates the login form via JavaScript. You can see that with the function "View Page Source" of your browser: in the resulting HTML code there is no `<form>` tag. And that is exactly what Scrapy sees. You must use a system to run the JavaScript code, maybe an headless browser.

[:edit] corrected sentence

Comment: hi  now i  can login instagram with two methods.  use cookies setting with scrapy. and use requests lib with headers and cookies.but FormRequest is not necessary. thanks for you answer.